# Keep getting a key error when using the data_editor (streamlit)

Tags: python, session-state, streamlit

I have financial data regarding a single company and I would like to have the user input/alter certain values. However, when trying to save the state I keep getting key errors that the column I am trying to change cannot be found. Is there a better way to update the df?

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st


df_company_data = {'2022': [1000, 1000, 1000],
                   '2021': [1000, 1000, 1000],
                   '2020': [1000, 1000, 1000]}


# Save state
if 'df_company_data' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.df_company_data = df_company_data
        
# Create callback
def save_edits(df):
    st.session_state.df_company_data = df

# Display dataframe
st.subheader('Key financial items (in millions):')

edited_df = st.data_editor(st.session_state.df_company_data, use_container_width=True) 
st.button('Save Changes', on_click=save_edits, args=(edited_df))
```

Answer (score 1):

`df_company_data` is a dictionary, not a pandas `dataframe`. But the `st.data_editor` expects a pandas `DataFrame` object, lets convert it, also the `on_click` parameter of `st.button` only triggers the function when the button is clicked, and the args parameter expects an iterable.

edit: lets try with st.data_editor:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df_company_data = pd.DataFrame({'2022': [1000, 1000, 1000],
                                '2021': [1000, 1000, 1000],
                                '2020': [1000, 1000, 1000]})

if 'df_company_data' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.df_company_data = df_company_data

def save_edits(df):
    st.session_state.df_company_data = df

st.subheader('Key financial items (in millions):')

edited_df = st.data_editor(st.session_state.df_company_data, on_change=save_edits, key="data_editor")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry that I did not repsond sooner. 

This does not allow for the user to change anything though right? I tried converting the 'df_company_data' to a pandas dataframe, but still get a key error. I would really like to make it work with the st.data_editor, if possible.

Comment: You welcome :)) I udpated my answer

Comment: In the above example, how is `df` in `save_edits` being supplied?

Comment: @scottlittle We could obtain the edited dataframe directly from st.data_editor, the "Save Changes" button would be then used to update the session state with the edited dataframe when clicked, this way No separate callback function is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal working example of how to implement this. It saves the `edited_df` as a `session_state` variable. I added a copy of the dataframe at the end to prove that the original dataframe is actually edited after clicking the `Save Changes` button.

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df_company_data = pd.DataFrame({'2022': [1000, 1000, 1000],
                                '2021': [1000, 1000, 1000],
                                '2020': [1000, 1000, 1000]})

if 'df_company_data' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.df_company_data = df_company_data
if 'edited_df' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.edited_df = df_company_data.copy()

def save_edits():
    st.session_state.df_company_data = st.session_state.edited_df

st.subheader('Key financial items (in millions):')

st.session_state.edited_df = st.data_editor(st.session_state.df_company_data)
st.button('Save Changes', on_click=save_edits)

st.write('Copy of updated dataframe:')
st.dataframe(st.session_state.df_company_data.copy())
```